# Read data from server in a better way in Android

Tags: android, http, android-listview, android-asynctask

I need to make http calls at every step of my app to get the response(in JSON) from server and display in list, grid views. Is there any better way to achieve this? Is this really the best way : http://smartmobsolution.blogspot.in/2014/02/the-best-way-toaccess-data-from-web-in.html ? Any third party libraries available to make the tasks simpler and faster like Connecting to web, Synchronizing with main thread, handling config changes etc?

Comment: Its depend on the situation in what form your server have the data?

Comment: Why don't you create your own static method that takes in url and params ( json post data, query strings, cookies etc..) and returns you the JSON object returned. Write code once and reuse everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging the example on that link, it's getting a JSON array or something on those lines, from the url, so you can use the [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) library to get the JSON from the url, and using a `JsonObjectRequest` you will get a `JSONObject` directly without any further parsing.

A sample request (you'll still need to add it to a queue and run the queue), would be something like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
    url, null,
    new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Generly we use HTTP to get data from server.and time taken by request is depends on the data quantity. but there are many libraries also to get fast response data from server.currently i just came across with **VOLLEY**. this library is 4-5 time faster then HTTP.so i recomment you to go with this. Well,below the the two best refrences to use this lib:

1). [volley By Javageeks](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library)

2).[Androidhove.info](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. Using JSON is good. XML may be better in some cases.

It also depends which system you are using on the Webserver. OKHttp for example support spdy which let you save some bandwidth and increase the request speed.

For parsing you may want to use JSON for simple stuff. You can also check SOAP which uses XML.

Using Volley is not recommend because it's slow and it does not support multipartentity pretty well.